# Hazrat Abu Bakr altercation with Hazrat Aisha?

Tags: hadith, history, source-identification, sahaba, aisha

Is this narration authentic?

"Once there was an altercation between the Prophet and Hazrat Ayesha when they found Hazrat Abu Bakr as judge. Hazrat Ayesha said to the Prophet: You speak but don’t speak except truth. At once Hazrat Abu Bakr gave her such a slap that blood began to ooze out from her mouth”.

Ihya Ulum-id-din by Imam Ghazali, Volume 2 page 37, Chapter “The secrets of marriage”, English translation by Maulana Fazlul Karim

Comment: What is the relation to sharia to this (you added a shari'a tag)? AFAIK the story is well known and wide spread Abu Bakr hit his daughter as she had a dispute with her Husband pbuh and he acted as a intermediate between them and in front of her father (in his opinion) acted or said something which was inappropriate to say to the Messenger of Allah pbuh. But AFAIK that doesn't mean it has backup in sunnah, so one could check it. But what is the use or benefit of knowing this happened? And why you quote a hadith out of context?

Comment: Im not quoting out of context i found some of these questions in anti muslims sites or shia sites so i come here to get clarification, to know if these narrations are authentic. For the purpose of edification i want to defend my faith from islamophobes and study ahadeeths.

Comment: This would be a better question if you put some context and explained why you even asked this. (Integrating your comment into the question might do just that. But make sure to cutout any prejudiced reference to other sects.) Btw, so far as the controversial figure of Aisha is concerned, you might also be interested in this Q&A as well: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2397/why-did-ayesha-battle-with-ali-a-s-in-the-battle-of-the-camel-jamal